# compare post time with current time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

I have a button with action, but before taking the action I need to check the last user's post if it is before 12 hours or not, if yes I will not allow to post, if yes I will processed to post

I tried with this code but it looks like something wrong!
I changed it from the api to return numbers, and same error appears !

```
   @IBAction func SubmitAd(_ sender: Any) {
    
    //LastPost:"time": "2021-01-30 18:29:05"


    if LastPost < "12" {
        print("You Can not Post now")
    } else {
        if (TitleLBL.text!.isEmpty || MessageLBL.text!.isEmpty || PhotoArray.count==0 || sectionName.isEmpty){
            ShowFillAlert()
        }else{
            
            ShowGuideAlert()
        }
    }
}
```

error is
Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two '[String : String]' operands

my php api

```js
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<?php
require_once '../config/app.php';
require_once '../config/database.php';
$mob=$_REQUEST["mob"];


$se=array("status"=>"","data"=>array());

$userEsxist = $mysqli->query("SELECT time FROM `requests` where phone = '$mob' ORDER BY `requests`.`time` DESC
");

if(!$userEsxist->num_rows){
$se["status"]=false;

} 
else
{
    $foundUser = $userEsxist->fetch_assoc();
    $se["status"]=true;
    $se["data"]=$foundUser;
}
echo json_encode($se);
?>
```

Comment: "before 12 hours", what does this mean? Less than 12 hours old or before 12 o'clock? And what type is LastPost?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I mean if the the user posted in the last 12 hours since his last post, LastPost is datetime and the format is on the question too

Comment: datetime is not a swift type so I ask again, what type is LastPost or is datetime some custom type?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson LastPost is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I propose.
It first **converts the string to a Date** using DateFormatter. Then it **adds 12 hours** to the date. Finally it checks if the new date (where 12 hours were added) is bigger (read after) the current date.

```
@IBAction func SubmitAd(_ sender: Any) {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    // Setting date formatter to read dates like "2021-01-30 18:29:05".
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "y-M-d HH:mm:ss"

    let postDate = dateFormatter.date(from: LastPost)!

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    // Adding 12 hours to the post date.
    let newPostAllowedDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 12, to: postDate)!

    //LastPost Time Format in Database: 2021-01-30 18:29:05.
    if newPostAllowedDate > Date() {
        print("You Can not Post now")
    } else {
        if (TitleLBL.text!.isEmpty || MessageLBL.text!.isEmpty || PhotoArray.count==0 || sectionName.isEmpty){
            ShowFillAlert()
        }else{

            ShowGuideAlert()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my api to return numbers but same error appears

Comment: ??? Why did you change it to return numbers ? I didn't ask you to change anything, leave it like before and it will work !

Comment: Yes, it worked thanks, but I want to change the value from the api too maybe later I will change it to 8 hours instead of 12 hours that's why @Titouan

Comment: @jacob you can’t completely change your question like that, it makes all existing answers and comments irrelevant in worst case and is rude against those that have tried to help you

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no he answered my question and I revert to the old code and question, sorry guy's